# Visual Studio Code will be updated after it restarts

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, code

Everytime we open [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), we get the below pop up.

[image: Visual Studio Code will be updated after it restarts]

> Visual Studio Code will be updated after it restarts

When it *restarts*, it **again** shows the same pop up.

Is there a problem in my editor? If this is some bug then does it affects anything else which is hidden?

Comment: Do you have administrator rights on the computer?  The only thing I can think of is that VS is trying to update but can't because of insufficient rights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a permissions error (oddly enough). Try running `VSCode` using administrator rights, and then update the program and see what happens upon restart.